# Trying to create a fixed nav-bar at the top of my page, but when I scroll down there is a gap right above the nav bar

Tags: html, css, web

The nav bar is not at the very top of the browser window. How can i fix this?

I encourage you to put in my code and run it to get a preview.

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Website(CSS).css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hunter's Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav-left">
                    <li id="twitter">
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/#"><img src="Twitter.png" width="75" height="75" alt="Twitter" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="instagram">
                        <a href="http://instagram.com/#"><img src="Instagram.png" width="75" height="75" alt="Instagram"/></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="quora">
                        <a href="http://quora.com/#"><img src="Quora.jpg" width="125" height="54" alt="Quora" /></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav-right">
                    <li id="future-plans">
                        <a href="insert link">Future Plans</a>
                    </li>
                    <li ="contact">
                        <a href="inset link">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="layer"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Learn more about me.</h1>
                <p>
                    Click <a href="insert link">here</a> to learn more about my future.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code:**
You can ignore the notes, they're just to remind me of what needs to be done.

```
/* Get the individual social media links to be pretty spaced out from each other, 
get the whole box of social image links to be closer to the left border. Get the nav header to be positioned as absolute. Get the -
.nav-right to have better font. To be bigger font, and to pushed a little more to the left of the nav box. */

body {
    border: 2px solid green;
}

.nav {
    /* Play around with height, try and get edges curved 
    Try making .jumbotron image to be full sized w/o cropping & 1110 width or whatever */
    background-color: red;
    height: 11%;
    width: 98%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.nav ul {
    display: inline;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.nav li  {
    display: inline;
    border: 2px solid black; 
}

.nav .nav-left {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.nav .nav-right {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.jumbotron {
    height: 515px;
    width: 1110px;
    background-image: url('Website .jumbotron.jpeg'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 120px;
    border: 2px solid black;
} 

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(76,76,76, 0.3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.jumbotron .container {
    position: relative;
    top: 240px;
    left: 26px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Shift', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 36px;
}
.jumbotron p {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text';
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "small gap between the bottom of the browser and the top of the nav bar"? I guess you are talking about the gap at the top of the navigation bar?

Comment: Heres the problem: http://imgur.com/I1cbILv  Its the gap right above the red nav-bar. And excuse the bad css, all the borders are just there so I can see the containers of different things, and things are not aligned yet lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to have your nav bar at the very top of the window just add this line to your CSS:

```
.nav {
  top: 0;
}
```

I suggest a gerenal layout like this (inside of the `<body>` of course):

```
<div id="wrap-out">
  <div id="wrap-in">
    <nav id="nav"><a href="#">link1</a> | <a href="#">link2</a></nav>
    <div id="content">
      <h1>some kind of standard layout...</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">(C) by Mr. Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap-out {
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrap-in {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

BTW: next time if you ask a question would be very smart to give a CODEPEN or FIDDLE

See this http://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/wBqhc?editors=110 one and play around

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I tried multiple times to put "margin: 0px;" in my .nav code block, but that didn't work, why is that?

Comment: its because of `position: fixed`

Comment: Overthink meaning second guess?

Comment: The css is indeed terrible right now, but i have yet to make it look nice

Comment: In general you should avoid positionate containers (fixed). Why? Sorry @Hunter this would need to much explanation. Go on like you started after getting more experienced you maybe will say that i was right. But wait i will give a short edit to my answer to give just a litte suggestion. just a mom :)

Comment: Haha, ok no problem at all. I am open to critique and advice, for I can use all the help I can get. I suppose, however, ill learn the hard way since this is my first ever project and just trying to get my feet wet!

Comment: Hey nevermind - i can see you doing a good job. And its just normal that you will do things completely different with growing skills.

Comment: As you can see in my edit or http://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/wBqhc?editors=110 this is a layout that is fluid.

Comment: i gave another edit with updated `max-width` and `min-width` value. best would be to have a look at the pen. regards :)

Comment: to really see the advantage of this layout style you have to enlarge and minimize the browser window. then you will recognize its fluid behavior.

Answer (score 2):

To stick the nav bar on the top without having that gap add the following code to your css file:

```
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```